# asp.net gridview columns move by themselves when clicking on rows

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have an asp.net gridview which almost everytime, certain columns move position for no reason, but only happens on IE, not on firefox.

This happens when I click on its rows.

So for example when you first go into the page, the gridview looks as intended.
You click on row 1, and everything looks fine.
You click on row 2, and column 2 for no reason expands to be double it allocated width. 
Also the aligment of column 4 (for example) changes from left to right, etc

The values are very short, so it's not a question of expanding tis width automatically as there is plenty of column space to fit.

Then I click on row 3 and everything goes back to how it should be.

The funny thing is that it only happens in IE, same grid in Firefox looks great, nothing moves.

Anyone knows the reason for this happening and how to avoid it ?

Comment: There must be a long field value in row 2 / perhaps leading spaces which will make it look like not long. can you try this and let us know what difference if any:  gvDataTable.Attributes.Add("style", "word-break:keep-all;word-wrap:normal")

Comment: checked if any leading spaces. Unfortunately there is none. I have checked all the rows where the "error" occurs, none of the fields within the row have leading spaces in them.

Comment: using gvDataTable.Attributes.Add("style", "word-break:keep-all;word-wrap:normal") unfortunately makes no difference.